# Comparación de dos ARRAY en VisualBasic

Tags: array, vb, visual, basic

tengo un .CSV con dos columnas, uno con licencias y otro con numero de serie de cada equipo.

Logró meter en un array las dos columnas, pero necesitaría comparar, es decir, tengo un equipo con su respectivo número de serie y busca en la columna de los números de serie, una vez encontrada, coge la licencia correspondiente y la guardar en una variable.

Gracias

---

Hello, I have a . CSV file with two columns, one with licenses and one with serial number for each computer.

He managed to put the two columns in an array, but he would need to compare, that is, I have a computer with its respective serial number and it looks in the column of serial numbers, once found, it takes the corresponding license and saves it in a variable.

Thank you

Comment: El idioma del sitio es el español, así que es innecesario que agregues la versión en inglés. En su lugar, pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Además, [visual] y [basic] no son lo mismo que [visual-basic]... Al colocar el mouse sobre las etiquetas lo notarás :) Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.